# MSO (Monadic second-order logic) Logic On Words

Tags: automata, logic, first-order-logic

Let L be a language over $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$ that contains all words, where the length $|w|_b$ (number of all b's) has remainder 1 if divided by 3.

MSO logic over words are definded as follow:
[image]

I want to express this language using MSO logic. But my problem is how can I count the b's to calculate the reminder? So it would be easiert if I just look on $|w|$, cause I could use max.

Comment: The situation you described happens to be a typical example of a language that can be recognized by a deterministic finite automata. Is there a way to translate DFAs into MSOs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the following: There are three disjoint sets $X_1,X_2,X_0$ that together hold the $b$-positions of the string. The last $b$ is in set $X_1$,